# Swift: How to replace uppercase symbols in array

Tags: arrays, swift, find-occurrences

This is the code that replaces cyrillic symbols to latin:

```
let cyr = ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "Б"]
let latin = ["a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "B"]
var original = self.input.text        
for i in 0..<cyr.count {
    let target = cyr[i]
    let destination = latin[i]  
    original = original?.replacingOccurrences(of: target, with: destination, options: String.CompareOptions(rawValue: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive.rawValue | NSString.CompareOptions.literal.rawValue), range: nil)
    self.output.text = original;
```

But it doesn't replace uppercase symbols to upper if i add them in array. It either replaces all lowercases to upper, either upper to lower. How to make it differentiate if it's uppercase symbol or lower and replace it respectively?

Comment: Unrelated but `String.CompareOptions(rawValue: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive.rawValue | NSString.CompareOptions.literal.rawValue)` is horrible. Replace it with `[.caseInsensitive, .literal]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `caseInsensitive` option and add the uppercase letters to the arrays.

```
let cyr = ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "Б", "А", ...]
let latin = ["a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "B", "A", ...]
var original = self.input.text        
for i in 0..<cyr.count {
    let target = cyr[i]
    let destination = latin[i]  
    original = original?.replacingOccurrences(of: target, with: destination, options: [.literal], range: nil)
}
self.output.text = original
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `caseInsensitive` option when you want a case *sensitive* search and replacement. Your code can also be simplified to

```
let cyr = ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "Б"]
let latin = ["a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "B"]

var text = "абвгдБ"

for (src, dest) in zip(cyr, latin) {
    text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: src, with: dest)
}
print(text) // abvgdB
```

Having said that, what you really might want is a *transliteration* to latin:

```
let original = "абвгдБ"
let trans = original.applyingTransform(.toLatin, reverse: false) ?? original
print(trans) // abvgdB
```

Comment: Can you pls help me out on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814962/map-value-in-particular-key-in-array-of-dictionary